# How do I set files uploaded with filepicker.io to s3 from other services (facebook, instagram, etc...) as public

Tags: filepicker.io

in the store_options that I provide to pickAndStore, setting:

```
access: 'public'
```

works to make the uploaded file public for files i upload from my computer.

When I upload a file through the modal dialog from, say, facebook or instagram, the file uploaded to s3 has not been set as public.  S3 returns a 403 Forbidden when I try to access my file.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug on filepicker's end?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417381/s3-access-public-not-working-for-files-from-internet-urls

Answer (score 0):

Filepicker dev here. There was a bug on our side that has now been fixed. Thanks for the patience.