# S3 access: 'public' not working for files from internet URLs

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to use ink file picker's library to allow users to upload images to my S3 bucket. This works great for files from the file system, but files from the internet somehow don't have their permissions set correctly, so the returned path is not publicly readable.

```
            store_options = {
                path: 'product/'+product_url+'/',
                access: 'public'
                };

            filepicker.pickAndStore({},store_options,function(InkBlobs){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(InkBlobs));
            });
```

There aren't a lot of knobs to turn here -- anyone have some advice?

Comment: I still don't know why filepicker acts differently for the two types of uploads, but I worked around this problem by changing my bucket policy to allow all users to read objects.

Comment: You may also need to make sure that Filepicker has the `PutObjectACL` so that they can actually set the flag.